# Browser ignores download attribute

Tags: html, button, download

I need help. My download button:

```html
<button type="button" download="logo.svg" href="[SVG_URL]">Download SVG</button>
```

it is supposed to download an .svg file, but the download attribute is not working. It only opens the file in a new tab. It happens with firefox and chrome also.

**Here's the problem [live](https://worlds-most-frustrating-button.glitch.me/).**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an anchor tag to make something downloadable. 
Like

```html
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>Click to Download</a>
```

But in case you want a button with a downloadable link, here is it

```html
<button><a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>Chick Here</a></button>
```

Just put the anchor tag with an attribute "download" inside a button.

To read more about anchor tags [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

In your case, as I saw from your site, use the code snippet below

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" download="https://cdn.glitch.com/63be2122-7b8d-4d1e-85a5-7d557ae54cc5%2FUPS.svg?1555285173725" href="" target="_blank">Download SVG</a>
```

Here, instead of putting the URL in href we are giving it to the download attribute.

Comment: It still opens in a new tab. I edited my post and added a link to the problem live.

Comment: Please check my last edit, I added a new code snippet that will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but how do I give it a new filename when the download attribute is taken? My browser calls it an .html file when it is really a .svg file.

Comment: I am afraid you can do that. Because the download works on same-origin URLs. To change the name with download attribute you need to give the link inside href tag. But that not possible for your case as you are using URL.